# Why decremented of NULL not negative in this array?

Tags: php

I have tried this code

```
$a = array_fill(0, 4, NULL);
$a[0]++;
++$a[1];
$a[2]--;
--$a[3];
var_dump($a);
```

**Result:**

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> int(1)
    [1]=> int(1)
    [2]=> NULL
    [3]=> NULL
}
```

Why value of 2 and 3 index is not negative?

Comment: Why do you expect the _index_ to go negative? The _values_ don't go negative because `NULL` in PHP is really weird. It's all to do with the loosely-typed nature of the language

Comment: The OP doesn't expect the _index_ to be negative, but the values specified by those indices.

Comment: that's a candidate for inclusion on http://phpsadness.com/.

Comment: @SirDarius Or [/r/lolphp](http://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/1i2pa1/null_cant_be_decremented_but_incrementing_it_is/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Use the source, Luke**

As usual, the answer lies in the source. PHP uses the following two functions internally to perform the increment and decrement operations:

[`ZEND_API int increment_function(zval *op1)`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1794)

[`ZEND_API int decrement_function(zval *op1)`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1845)

These operations modify the `op1` argument based on its type (`NULL` is a type); inside `increment_function()` you can see the following branch [in the code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1809):

```c
case IS_NULL:
    ZVAL_LONG(op1, 1);
    break;
```

The above code changes the type of `op1` into a number and sets its value to `1`.

Conversely, `decrement_function()` offers no such branch and therefore the [default action](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1884) will be performed:

```c
default:
    return FAILURE;
```

Running this code won't actually yield any observable failure, because the return values are absorbed in the Zend VM, but the variable definitely isn't updated either.

**It's not a bug(tm)**

You may be surprised to know that this behaviour, including that for boolean values, is actually [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> **Note:** The increment/decrement operators do not affect boolean values. Decrementing `NULL` values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in `1`.

Regarding booleans:

```
$a = true;
var_dump($a--); // true
$a = false;
var_dump($a++); // false
```

Regarding strings:

```
$letter = 'A';
var_dump(++$letter); // B
var_dump(--$letter); // B
```

Comment: It is not a bug because it is documented?

Comment: @soc [What's a software bug ?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) : A software bug is an error, flaw, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that produces an incorrect or **unexpected** result, or causes it to behave in **unintended** ways. But since it's documented then it's an **expected** and **intended** behaviour.

Comment: @soc The slight irony in that part may have fallen on blind eyes, so I've made a slight edit. That said, I'm surprised to see you drawn to this question, given your [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968913/which-language-to-choose-for-a-live-web-application/2969493#2969493) [contributions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3922387/1338292) to this tag ;-)

Comment: Coming straight from r/lolphp. Oh, and thanks for stalking and down-voting me.

Comment: @soc I've always wondered what reddit was about ;-) interesting conversations in there; btw, the stalking was made public in my previous comment, not sure where the downvote came from.

Answer (score 23):

Weird, but [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) on the Incrementing/Decrementing Operators php doc page:

> Note: The increment/decrement operators do not affect boolean values. Decrementing NULL values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1.

Comment: Documented -> not a bug ;-)

Comment: @zerkms but to say the very least, an egregious violation of the [Principle of the Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Answer (score 4):

Strange. I don't know their deciding factor to this but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1934), you'll see that if it's dealing with a NULL, it sets it to 1 (not increment).

```
case IS_NULL:
    ZVAL_LONG(op1, 1);
    break;
```

The [decrement](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1983) function doesn't deal with NULL at all and goes straight to FAILURE:

```
default:
    return FAILURE;
```

As others mentioned, it is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

> **Note:** The increment/decrement operators do not affect boolean values. Decrementing `NULL` values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in `1`.