# Uninitialized variables in PHP

Tags: php, initialization

[The PHP manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a
> very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of
> their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans
> default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g.
> used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty
> array.

I was playing around with uninitialized variables for golfing, but the program didn't do what I expected it to do. Upon examination, I noticed this weird behavior (all used variables are uninitialized):

```
php > $a = $a + 1;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in php shell code on line 1
php > $b = $b - 1;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: b in php shell code on line 1
php > $c++;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: c in php shell code on line 1
php > $d--;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: d in php shell code on line 1
php > var_dump($a);
int(1)
php > var_dump($b);
int(-1)
php > var_dump($c);
int(1)
php > var_dump($d);
NULL
```

`+ 1`, `- 1`, and `++` work as described in the manual. However, `--` doesn't.

`$a`, `$b`, and `$c` can be used for counting, afterwards. But `$d--;`, won't change `$d`'s value because `$d` is `NULL`.

Why is `$d` set to `NULL`, not to `-1`?

Using prefix operators yields the same results, by the way: The variable is set to `1` for `++$v;` but to `NULL` for `--$v;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> Note: …Decrementing NULL values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1.

So, an unitialized variable gets a NULL value. Incrementing this value gets the 1 (as NULL + 1). But an attempt to decrementing it doesn't have any effect as described in the documentation.

Also, there is [a very good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606791/1220930) in the relevant topic.

It may seem counterintuitive, but it is a consequence of the typing model of the language. So, to avoid this behavior, just always follow the good practices: always initialize a variables and beware of arithmetic operations on the non-numeric values.

Comment: So decrementing a variable is different from subtracting 1 from it, isn't it? Otherwise, `$v = $v - 1;` would set `$v` to `NULL`, too. Can you elaborate on this and perhaps also elaborate how the described behavior is a consequence of PHP's typing model?

Comment: > decrementing a variable is different from subtracting 1 - exactly

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know _why_ NULL values behaves so with decrement. Perhaps just someone decided that there should be so :)